# Accept Invite in iCal - without Mail.app

Tags: macos, mail.app, ical

Whenever I want to reply to an iCal event it opens up Mail.app to send the response.  I don't use Mail.app and use Sparrow instead.  Sparrow is set as the default mail client but that doesn't seem to make any difference.  Is there any way to make iCal not open up Mail.app and use "Insert any other mail client here" instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a pre written apple script solution for this and fairly easy instructions that any apple script novice should be able to follow. You can find the download and instructions [here](https://github.com/JohanB/ical_sparrow).

Comment: Strange, I looked at this the other day and when I opened my terminal I didn't see the file and assumed it had changed in the switch from SL to L.  You win, i lose LOL